# D3 visual - quasi waffle plot but not contiguous

Tags: d3.js, waffle-chart

[image]

- I am trying to trying to replicate the example image enclosed but via d3
  specifically
- Ideally i am trying to find a d3 template online that is
  similiar to this and use it and bend it from there
- I wish to have a list of cities, and then each row would have a colored rectangle to symbolize the presence of some alphabet value, for instance Houston has A1/A2 and D1/D2, and Dallas has A1/A2, B1/B2, and D1/D2. This is somewhat like a waffle plot, but with non-contiguous concept where they aren't all bunched together.

  - This is very easy to do obviously in excel but looking to inherently do it in d3 and grow it from there...

Comment: I think this is actually easier to do with just straight rectangles in a grid versus 'waffles'...